# Azure Container Service fails to install docker-engine

Tags: azure-container-service

I have deployed a new resource group and kubernetes cluster using the acs-engine to extract articles and release via these ARM templates in VSTS. The kubernetes cluster is created however when you ssh into the master docker-engine has not been installed. Running

```
`systemctl status kubelet`
```

shows that the service is dead and when you try to run it says the docker.service is dead. This cannot start because the docker engine is not there.

```
Reading package lists...
May  4 17:32:27 ubuntu cloud-init[2488]: W: GPG error: 
https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-xenial InRelease: The 
following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not 
available: NO_PUBKEY F76221572C52609D
May  4 17:32:27 ubuntu cloud-init[2488]: W: The repository 
'https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-xenial InRelease' is not 
signed.
May  4 17:32:27 ubuntu cloud-init[2488]: Reading package lists...
May  4 17:32:27 ubuntu cloud-init[2488]: Building dependency tree...
May  4 17:32:27 ubuntu cloud-init[2488]: Reading state information...
May  4 17:32:27 ubuntu cloud-init[2488]: The following additional         
packages will be installed:
May  4 17:32:27 ubuntu cloud-init[2488]:   aufs-tools cgroupfs-mount 
libltdl7
May  4 17:32:27 ubuntu cloud-init[2488]: Suggested packages:
May  4 17:32:27 ubuntu cloud-init[2488]:   mountall
May  4 17:32:27 ubuntu cloud-init[2488]: The following NEW packages 
will be installed:
May  4 17:32:27 ubuntu cloud-init[2488]:   aufs-tools cgroupfs-mount 
docker-engine libltdl7
May  4 17:32:27 ubuntu cloud-init[2488]: 0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 
0 to remove and 176 not upgraded.
May  4 17:32:27 ubuntu cloud-init[2488]: Need to get 19.4 MB/19.5 MB of 
archives.
May  4 17:32:27 ubuntu cloud-init[2488]: After this operation, 102 MB 
of additional disk space will be used.
May  4 17:32:27 ubuntu cloud-init[2488]: WARNING: The following 
packages cannot be authenticated!
May  4 17:32:27 ubuntu cloud-init[2488]:   docker-engine
May  4 17:32:27 ubuntu cloud-init[2488]: E: There were unauthenticated 
packages and -y was used without --allow-unauthenticated
May  4 17:32:27 ubuntu cloud-init[2488]: Failed to restart 
docker.service: Unit docker.service not found.
May  4 17:32:28 ubuntu cloud-init[2488]: usermod: group 'docker' does 
not exist
```

When you try to run an 
    `apt-get install docker-engine` 
it fails as you can see above.

Running 
    `sudo apt-get install -y --allow-unauthenticated docker-engine` 
allow you to install the docker engine and start the kubelet service. You can then access the cluster from the master.

However, there is no .kube/config created so you cannot access this from an external source. I could create the .kube/config from the master and am investigating this now.

This needs to be fixed as I am automating environment deployment.

Comment: So having redeployed this serveral times I have managed to get it to the point where the kubernetes master is up however, only 2 of the 4 agents are up. Two have the same error:

`sudo systemctl status kubelet
● kubelet.service - Kubelet
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

sudo systemctl start kubelet
Failed to start kubelet.service: Unit docker.service not found.`

I really need this up and running asap. Please help

Comment: Looks like this might be a related
`gpg: requesting key 2C52609D from hkp server ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net
gpg: keyserver timed out
gpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error`

Answer (score 1):

PR https://github.com/Azure/acs-engine/pull/498 fixed the failure to retreive GPG. Can you confirm that you are using latest acs-engine, and if so, please send the region where you are seeing this.

To confirm correct running, I just deployed the latest in ACS-Engine to us-west, and also verified our runners are not showing this issue across Azure regions.

Comment: I have got the latest acs-engine and am deploying into westeurope. I will try again now.

Comment: Exactly the same problem.

Comment: We're trying to narrow down the failure, and have been unable to repro in westeurope.  Can you confirm the cloud-init logs are showing failure to execute `curl --max-time 60 -fsSL https://aptdocker.azureedge.net/gpg`?  Also, please try to run that command yourself to see if you can reach it on the same machine.